# Text moving to next line after div

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

## Issue Details

Text is moving to next line after square.

Expected - Text should be right after the square.

Am I missing anything?

**[JS Fiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/2740kydp/)**

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div id="chartjsLegend" class="chartjsLegend">
          <div style="width:15px;height:15px;background-color:rgb(0, 0, 0)"></div>Q1 - 29.00%
          <div style="width:15px;height:15px;background-color:rgb(255, 0, 0)"></div>Q2 - 23.78%
          <div style="width:15px;height:15px;background-color:rgb(0, 255, 0)"></div>Q3 - 19.89%
          <div style="width:15px;height:15px;background-color:rgb(0, 0, 255)"></div>Q4 - 27.33%
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: If Bootstrap's container-fluid makes the div magically inline, then that is indeed a good question. Otherwise you need to not use a block element. inline-block would work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `div` is a block element it will span the entire row. That's why the text goes to the next line. To prevent this default behavior we need to explicitly change the div's `display` property to `inline-block`.

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
 </head>
 <body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
   
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
     <div id="chartjsLegend" class="chartjsLegend">
          <div>
              <div style="width:15px;height:15px;background-color:rgb(0, 0, 0);display:inline-block;"></div>Q1 - 29.00%
          </div>
     <div>
              <div style="width:15px;height:15px;background-color:rgb(255, 0, 0);display:inline-block;"></div>Q2 - 23.78%
          </div>
     <div>
              <div style="width:15px;height:15px;background-color:rgb(0, 255, 0);display:inline-block"></div>Q3 - 19.89%
          </div>
     <div>
        <div style="width:15px;height:15px;background-color:rgb(0, 0, 255);display:inline-block"></div>Q4 - 27.33%
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
     <div id="canvas-holder" style="width:200px;">
      <canvas id="chart-area" width="100" height="100" />    
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: can u give js fiddle link

Answer (score 0):

Use `float:left` in all `div`

```html
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div id="chartjsLegend" class="chartjsLegend">
                <div style="width:100%"> 
                    <div style="width:15px;height:15px;background-color:rgb(0, 0, 0);float:left"></div> Q1 - 29.00%
                </div>
                <div style="width:100%"> 
                    <div style="width:15px;height:15px;background-color:rgb(255, 0, 0);float:left"></div>Q2 - 23.78%
                </div>
                <div style="width:100%"> 
                    <div style="width:15px;height:15px;background-color:rgb(0, 255, 0);float:left"></div>Q3 - 19.89%
                </div>
                <div style="width:100%"> 
                    <div style="width:15px;height:15px;background-color:rgb(0, 0, 255);float:left"></div>Q4 - 27.33%
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div id="canvas-holder" style="width:200px;">
                <canvas id="chart-area" width="100" height="100" />    
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Codepen link: https://codepen.io/bhavik103/pen/oNNoVLo